# Sync data between C# and iphone app

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, synchronization

What I am looking for is an offline sync between a C# app running on a PC and an app on the iPhone connected to it.

- Is this possible at all?
- Is there a way to use iTunes app to access iPhone data.
- Can ActiveSync or any other API to sync data between PC and device.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be an unnecessary comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a server or wcf service which is called to pass data between two apps